# Existe IDE para desenvolver interface gráfica GTK?

Tags: c, ide, gtk

Quero desenvolver programas com interface para o Linux. Existe IDE para desenvolver interface gráfica em GTK no mesmo estilo do Visual Studio da Microsoft? O estilo que me refiro é o "arrasta e solta" utilizado para criar interface quando programado em VB.

Comment: Já  viu o Glade?

Comment: Estou pesquisando agora mesmo sobre ele.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O GTK já tem o [Glade](https://glade.gnome.org/).

Normalmente recomenda-se o [Anjuta](http://anjuta.org/).

Pode-se usar o [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/).

O [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) tem alguma coisa.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Você acha o Anjuta melhor ?

Comment: Coimo eu acho todos ruins, prefiro não opinar sobre isso.